# django.urls.resolvers.URLResolver._reverse_with_prefix() argument after ** must be a mapping, not set

Tags: python, django

Olá estou tentando fazer um e-commerce com Django, fui seguindo um tutorial até a criação dos produtos, a página funcionou ok (sem produtos e categorias), quando adicionei uma categoria e um produto pelo http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ ele me retornou este erro ao tentar entrar na url dos produtos (http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/).

[image: imagem do erro na pagina]

[image: Traceback]

O meu get_absolute_url está desta forma:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("products:detail", kwargs={"slug", self.slug})
```

ele está presente dentro do meu models, da seguinte forma:

```
class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="products", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/%Y/%m/%d", blank=True)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(unique=True, always_update=False, populate_from="name")

    objects = models.Manager()
    available = AvailableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("name",)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("products:detail", kwargs={"slug", self.slug})
```

porém vejo que o erro esta dando ao entrar em /products/ e não em /products/nome_do_produto/

Comment: Thiago, no seu `get_absolute_url` você está passando`{"slug", self.slug}` para o reverse, porém o método espera receber um dicionário e você está passando um `set`. Você precisa trocar `{"slug", self.slug}` por `{"slug": self.slug}` pois são estruturas de dados diferentes.

Comment: Muito obrigado, não tinha reparado nisso. Resolveu o problema!